# How to get numer of repeating elements in PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays

Sometimes we need to get only the count of repeating elements from an array, or the count of each elements in an array

```
    $array = array(123, 'abc', 26, 'swat', 1, 'swat', 83);
```

I would like to print:

```
    123 (1)
    abc (1)
    26 (1)
    swat (2)
    1 (1)
    83 (1)
```

Comment: Why did you ask question since you would provide the answer

Comment: Could this be a homework question (?), then you should add the `homework` tag, so people can answer appropriate.

Comment: FYI http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use php function [array_count_values](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

```
<?php
    $array = array(123, 'abc', 26, 'swat', 1, 'swat', 83);
    print_r(array_count_values($array));
?>
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [123] => 1
    [abc] => 1
    [26] => 1
    [swat] => 2
    [1] => 1
    [83] => 1
)
```